# ImageMagick not displaying backslash on font to png conversion

Tags: imagemagick

When I run the following command:

```
magick -size 64x80 -font DejaVu-Sans-Mono-Bold canvas:none -pointsize 64 -gravity West -draw "text 0, 0 '\\'" backslash.png
```

It makes a file called "backslash.png" but with no letter on the picture.
Could anyone explain why this is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: I solved the problem by rerunning the command many times, adding a backslash each time. Turns out, you need to have seven before it works

Comment: Try using -annotate in place of -draw.  See if you get it to work with "\\"